# ParametricNDSolveValue::prange: Invalid non-numeric value -y for parameter y

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{-y*a'[x] == (a[x]^2 - 1)*x + a[x], 
   a[-10] == 0.6}, a, {x, -100, 100}, {y}]

sol[1]

NIntegrate[sol[y][t] /. t -> 1, {y, -10, 10}]

Comment: ayyappan, please improve the typeset of your code. If you don't know how to, check the comment under this post: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1977/1871

Answer (score 2):

Okay so first, take a look at [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502). It explains how to use [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html).

so encapsulate in a function:

```
solution[y_?NumericQ,t_?NumericQ]:=sol[y][t]
```

which works with

```
NIntegrate[solution[y,1],{y,0,10}]
```

> -3.52861

Attention: i changed you integrationinterval because the NDSolve has problems with values of $y<0$

Comment: Thanks. @Julien.  But i have to do NItegration with {y, -ymin, ymax}.